# Como somar um campo de uma determinada ID com vários registros?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A história é a seguinte: um político pode ser votado em várias `zonas`, por isso o motivo do mesmo `ID` de candidato conter vários registros dentro da tabela.

O `ID_CANDIDATO` sendo `120000000171`, ele tendo 6 registros no banco de dados referente as 6 zonas diferentes que ele recebeu votos.

Como montar uma `sql` que mostrará `1` registro com todas as informações desse candidato e o ***total*** de votos recebidos por este?

```
ID        ID_CANDIDATO       TOT_VOTOS
21        120000000171       339
45        120000000171       405
73        120000000171       513
88        120000000171       380
92        120000000171       752
96        120000000171       439
```

Um exemplo visual do que estou buscando está [***nesta página***](http://axitech.com.br/directory/wp-eleicoes/gera_banco.php). O último campo é o `TOT_VOTOS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o `SUM`. Para isso, será preciso agrupar os registros:

```
SELECT SUM(tot_votos) as total_votos FROM ... GROUP BY id_candidato
```

Para obter as informações do candidato na mesma pesquisa, você precisará de um `JOIN` com a tabela de candidatos:

```
SELECT SUM(tz.tot_votos) as total_votos, tc.*
    FROM tabela_zonas tz
    JOIN tabela_candidatos tc ON tc.id = tz.id_candidato
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY tz.id_candidato
```

Comment: Todos os dados estão dentro de uma mesma tabela. Pode me ajudar a extrair o `SUM` e o resto das informações? Obrigado.

Comment: `SELECT *, SUM(TOTAL_VOTOS) as total_votos FROM VOTACAO_CANDIDATO_MUN_ZONA_2012_MS WHERE NOME_MUNICIPIO = 'CAMPO GRANDE' GROUP BY SQ_CANDIDATO`, obrigado velho !!!

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar `SUM()` para somar os votos e `GROUP BY` para juntar os registros pelo código do seu candidato.

```
SELECT SUM(TOT_VOTOS) FROM sua_tabela
WHERE id_candadito = $seu_id GROUP BY id;
```

Você pode recuperar informações como nome e afins adicionando `JOIN`. Mas a princípio o `SQL` acima dará o resultado que você deseja.
Mas caso não seja o resultado esperado ou precise modificar ou adicionar algo, por favor avise!